# Isotope only shows up after filtering or resizing browser window

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, load, jquery-isotope

I'm using [Metafizzy's Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to display my wordpress posts, and the container won't display any of my items until I take some other action (like filtering or resizing the window).. then it "wakes up" and functions as usual. This is occurring in Chrome only. Has anyone experienced this or know of a solution?

Comment: Can you show your code?  There shouldn't be any issue using that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when loading in a page full of images. I simply set Isotope to run after all of the images had loaded:

```
$(function() {
    //on all images load

        $('img').on('load', function() {
            //Initialise Isotope
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem just now while i was creating an HTML template using ZURB Foundation 4, and before this page loaded, i resolved it by calling isotope before foundation and wrapping the isotope call in a window load callback like so:

```
// Load Isotope on window load
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.portfolio-items').isotope({
        itemSelector:'.portfolio-item'
    });
});

// Loaded foundation after isotope
$(document).foundation('orbit', {timer_speed:5000,bullets:false,orbit_transition_class: 'orbit-transitioning'});
```

Try wrapping your isotope call in a window on load callback, if that does not work then try loading it before any other jquery plugin, there might be conflicts.